# Label of React material-ui Select component displays over content

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following **material-ui** `Select` component:

```
<FormControl fullWidth className="attr-foreign-key">
    <InputLabel id={field+"-label"}>{catalog.title_singular}</InputLabel>
    <Select
        labelId={field+"-label"}
        id={field}
        value={value_name}
        onChange={this.handleChange(value_id)}
        renderValue={value_name => value_name}
     >
        <MenuItem value="">
          <em>Ninguno</em>
        </MenuItem>
        {
          this.state.choices? this.state.choices.map(choice => <MenuItem value={choice.name}>{choice.name}</MenuItem>): null
        }
   </Select>
</FormControl>
```

The problem is that it displays the label of the `Select` over its content:

[image]

It only displays well when the `Select` has the focus:

[image]

But it fails again when it looses it. I haven't found any reference for solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Material ui has a **props** in Textfield component to transform it to use select. Doing so you wont have the problem and it will be easier for you to use for the same result.

[link](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#select)

Code sample:

```
<TextField
      id="filled-select-currency"
      select
      label="Select"
      value={currency}
      onChange={handleChange}
      helperText="Please select your currency"
      variant="filled"
    >
      {currencies.map(option => (
        <MenuItem key={option.value} value={option.value}>
          {option.label}
        </MenuItem>
      ))}
    </TextField>
```

Hope it helps.